# Pulling Featured Images in to a WordPress Menu

Tags: wordpress

I've got a simple static list marked up like this that I'd like to turn in to a WordPress Menu:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"></a></li>
</ul>
```

I'd like each list item to link to a specific post, and pull in the Featured Image rather than the title. If I setup a default WordPress Menu it would output like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="post-1/">Blog Post 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="post-2/">Blog Post 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="post-3/">Blog Post 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="post-4/">Blog Post 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

How would I instead output it like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="post-1/"><img src="post-1-featured-img.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="post-2/"><img src="post-2-featured-img.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="post-3/"><img src="post-3-featured-img.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="post-4/"><img src="post-4-featured-img.png"></a></li>
</ul>
```

So essentially I'd just like to return the Featured Image of each post I specify in a WordPress Custom Menu rather than the post title.

Comment: You'll need to create a custom walker class, this post has lots of examples and guidance http://wpsmith.net/2011/tutorials/how-to-add-menu-descriptions-featured-images-to-wordpress-menu-items/

Comment: The custom walker stuff is way to complicated for something so easy. I solved this using some filters here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079190/add-featured-image-to-wp-nav-menu-items/26079191

Answer (score -1):

you can use to get the image but m think you cant get post feature in the menu from the default wp menu

```
$defaults = array(
                    'container' => '',
                    'container_class' => '',
                    'menu' => 'Main Menu',
                    'echo' => 1,
                    'items_wrap' => '<ul class="topmenu">%3$s</ul>',
                    'link_before'     => '<img src="post-1-featured-img.png"/>',
    'link_after'      => '<span class="menu_h_r"></span></a>'
                );

               wp_nav_menu($defaults);
```

to get the define image but m not sure you will find solution for you. try some plugins.

Comment: Thanks. This would be a custom WordPress Menu, and I don't want to hardcode the images in, they need to be dynamically generated - the Featured Image of each post. I simply want to return the Featured Image rather than the title.