# Wordpress - Menu with title and featured image

Tags: wordpress, menu

I'm trying to pull through a menu that includes the pages featured image and obviously it's name.

I have searched for assistance and so far found
[Pulling Featured Images in to a WordPress Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892953/pulling-featured-images-in-to-a-wordpress-menu)

But it gave me an error;

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in .. on line 22

The code is as follows;

```
<?php
$navMenu = wp_get_nav_menu_items('footer-services-menu'); /*/Pass Nav Menu_id or Name*/
$previousMenuParent = $level = 0;
foreach ($navMenu as $menu) {

    if($menu->menu_item_parent == 0)
    {
        $level = 0;
        echo '<li><a href="'. $menu->url .'">'. $menu->title .'</a>';
    }
    elseif($menu->menu_item_parent != '' && $menu->menu_item_parent != $previousMenuParent)
    {
        $level++;
        echo '<ul class="submenu">';
        echo '<li><a href="'. $menu->url .'">'. $menu->title .'</a>';
        $previousMenuParent = $menu->menu_item_parent;
    }
    elseif($previousMenuParent == $menu->menu_item_parent)
    {
        echo '</li><li><a href="'. $menu->url .'">';
        if($level == 3)
        {
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail($menu->ID);
        }
        echo $menu->title .'</a>';
    }
}
?>
```

Can anyone help work out why please and fix it

Thanks

Comment: `wp_get_nav_menu_items` return Array of menu items, otherwise false. make sure your `$navMenu` is `array` not `false`

Comment: try this plugin :https://wordpress.org/plugins/megamenu/

Comment: I've gotten the menu to pull through the title but still not images

Below is the code of the featured image so far
                         
echo $menu->title = has_post_thumbnail($menu->object_id) ? get_the_post_thumbnail($menu->object_id, 'thumbnail') : $menu->title;
                        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
var_dump($navMenu);
```

after the first row and you will see the reason of the problem. IMHO it returns false (because of invalid menu name/slug)

Comment: Yeah it was the invalid menu name which was weird, once I changed it to menu ID it worked, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to use walker menu in your menu as per below.
make menu from wp theme and call that menu in header.ph file as per below.
 wp_nav_menu( array(
                            'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                            'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
                            'walker'         => new cement_elegance_mega_menu,
                        ) );
```

And try to add your code in walker menu file that is working for me.